# unable to run main.dart , help me , i having issue with kotlin , in vs code ,same problem in vs android studio after using location library

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

I am building a Flutter app, and everything is fine but after installing the location library in Flutter, they started giving me errors when I run my app, the error is

"Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':location' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)"

kindy help me, anyone, I have tried lots of things, tried to change the version, etc. but not work help me

I want a solution to this error in Flutter

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle here ?

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

Comment: As  you wrote here it should be okay, are you still encountering this error ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to update the version code at build.gradle located at android\build.gradle path.

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

change the version no. of ext.kotlin_version.

Answer (score 0):

**Do the following:**

**Search for** `ext.kotlin_version = 1.4.20` in `Location` **library Gradle** ,
then change it to `1.5.20` or to **latest version**.